# How to put list values into two separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

This is the code I am working with currently.

```
data = {'ID': ['O1', 'O2', 'O3', 'O4'],'DATE': ['2010-09-09','2010-10-15','2011-02-09','2011-08-12'], 'RESULT': [1160, 6112, 21175, 10830]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) #putting into a dataframe
grouped=df.groupby('ID')['RESULT','DATE'].apply(list) #groupby method and putting into list
```

Running this code gives me the following table.

```
ID
O1    [1160,  2010-09-09]
O2    [6112,  2010-10-15]
O3    [21175, 2011-02-09]
O4    [10830, 2011-08-12]
```

I want the [RESULT, DATE] to be separated so the format becomes as below.

```
ID    VL      DATES
O1    1160    2010-09-09
O2    6112    2010-10-15
O3    21175   2011-02-09
O4    10830   2011-08-12
```

There are more than 100 rows so I am looking for a suitable way to put them in the table shown above.

Comment: FYI `list(df)` gives a list of column names and that's what's happening with that apply

Comment: Why not just rename the columns? `df = df.rename({'RESULT': 'VL', 'DATE': 'DATES'}, axis=1)`

Comment: It's not renaming the column problem, Richard. What you've given me below does not give the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `tolist` on the result and pass that to `pd.DataFrame` (here I'm using `pipe` to make it a nice one-liner):

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')[['RESULT','DATE']].apply(list).pipe(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist(), index=x.index, columns=['VL', 'DATE']))
        VL  DATE
ID              
O1  RESULT  DATE
O2  RESULT  DATE
O3  RESULT  DATE
O4  RESULT  DATE
```

Comment: Hi Richard and Either, sorry for not making myself clear. I've edited my code.